# Why this % when printing a single value of array

Tags: c

```
printf("%d" , marks [0][0];
```

Output
90%

I was printing a 2d array and this happened

Comment: The code shown will not output `90%`. Are you asking *how* to output `90%`?

Comment: The code shown is not even syntactically valid, much less a complete program whose behavior we could discuss.

Comment: @WeatherVane "The code shown will not output 90%" --> `%` due to [shell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75572310/2410359) appending a last line lacking a `'\n'`, not the program itself.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica so I see from an answer. My shell does not output `%` and it adds a newline anyway.

Answer (score 4):

That `%` is most likely the shell prompt.

Try using

```
 printf("%d\n", marks[0][0]);
```

so that the `90` (or whatever value should be printed) is displayed on a line of its own.